# Google Maps API - point of interests

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am working now on little project.

In one view i am returning data for google maps API (longitudes and latitudes).

Under the map I have to implement few buttons to add point of interests on the map in this location which is actually showed.

There could be some buttons/types of POI like schools, banks, atms etc.

So, let's go back. When I put all my markers on map how to add there points of interests?

I would like to get below data for them:

1. longitude (needed for show)
2. latitude
3. type
4. title
5. description

I know, that there is google local ajax search api, but I am not sure if it is correct way to do.

I know how to find this data using google maps interface, for example:

[Example Map](http://maps.google.pl/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=pl&geocode=&q=category:%22Banks+%26+Financial+Institutions%22&sll=51.510202,-0.12144&sspn=0.01859,0.05549&ie=UTF8&cd=1&ei=N4hUS7ynEc7AjAeWtNm4CA&radius=1.19&rq=1&ev=zi&hq=category:%22Banks+%26+Financial+Institutions%22&hnear=&z=15)

```
http://maps.google.pl/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=pl&geocode=&q=category:%22Banks+%26+Financial+Institutions%22&sll=51.510202,-0.12144&sspn=0.01859,0.05549&ie=UTF8&cd=1&ei=N4hUS7ynEc7AjAeWtNm4CA&radius=1.19&rq=1&ev=zi&hq=category:%22Banks+%26+Financial+Institutions%22&hnear=&z=15
```

but how to do this using API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Local Search API can be used to obtain a small number of such points at a time, as in [this example](http://www.google.com/uds/samples/places.html). Or you could just add the [Googlebar](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GGoogleBar) to your Maps AVI v2 map.

Access to large numbers of such points at once is not available from Google, and is generally not available for free.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Google, there are other data providers you can use. For example, the API at http://compass.webservius.com allows you to retrieve data on more than 16 million businesses in the US (including name, lat/long, business type / industry code, etc).

Comment: Nice - thanks for links. Unfortunately my project is outside US.

Answer (score -1):

The Google API is a Javascript API.

If I understand you correctly, you want to add markers on a Google Map using the Google Maps API.

The documentation suggests that either you hardcode your Markers or create one by creating a Marker Manager.

I have never used Google Maps API but if you want more info, visit the documentation [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/overlays.html).

Good luck!

Comment: I know how to put markers etc.

I want how to find needed data for POI.

Comment: Well, sorry for misunderstanding your question: 

You've mentioned one way of doing it (Ajax Local Search API), there's another way by doing Reverse Geocoding. I've found out from here (http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/e799e4ad916a8e90) with example here (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/examples/geocoding-reverse.html).

I don't know if that helps....Sorry!